# looping object card by entering data on array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

i want to make a looping card,

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="itemName">Nama</h5>
        <p class="card-text" id="itemDesc">Deskripsi barang</p>
        <p class="card-text">Rp Harga</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addCart">Tambahkan ke keranjang</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

by entering data through the array below

```
var items = [
    ['001', 'Keyboard Logitek', 60000, 'Keyboard yang mantap untuk kantoran', 'logitek.jpeg'], 
    ['002', 'Keyboard MSI', 300000, 'Keyboard gaming MSI mekanik', 'msi.jpeg'],
    ['003', 'Mouse Genius', 50000, 'Mouse Genius biar lebih pinter', 'genius.jpeg'],
    ['004', 'Mouse Jerry', 30000, 'Mouse yang disukai kucing', 'jerry.jpeg']
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Simple Iteration, I have used [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the final output and then appended it to the dom.

```js
var items = [
  ['001', 'Keyboard Logitek', 60000, 'Keyboard yang mantap untuk kantoran', 'logitek.jpeg'],
  ['002', 'Keyboard MSI', 300000, 'Keyboard gaming MSI mekanik', 'msi.jpeg'],
  ['003', 'Mouse Genius', 50000, 'Mouse Genius biar lebih pinter', 'genius.jpeg'],
  ['004', 'Mouse Jerry', 30000, 'Mouse yang disukai kucing', 'jerry.jpeg']
]

let data = items.reduce((acc, ele) => {

  acc += `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="pathtofolder/${ele[5]}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="itemName">${ele[1]}</h5>
        <p class="card-text" id="itemDesc">${ele[2]}</p>
        <p class="card-text">${ele[4]}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addCart">${ele[5]}</a>
    </div>
</div>`

  return acc;

}, '')


document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;
```

```html
<div id="data">

</div>
```

Comment: how can i insert the img? from img folder

Comment: I have updated the answer all you have to do is put the path of the folder where those images exists @phantomhive

Comment: thnkyou very much brother

Comment: Please accept the answer if that worked for you @phantomhive